# How to get character without numbers when iterating through std::string?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, iteration, pass-by-reference

I am trying to iterate through each character in std::string which was passed by reference and compare it to the first element of vector of strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool letterFound (const std::string &s){
    std::vector<std::string> vLetters = {"A", "B", "C"};
    for (auto &letter : s) {
        if (&letter == vLetters[0]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::string result = letterFound("AB")
                        ? "Letter [A] found"
                        : "Letter not found";
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If just one letter "A" passed to the function, then letter was found, but if I pass more than one letter, for example "AB", than actual value of the first character to compare is "65 'A'", not "A". The second character is "66 'B'".

How to get exactly one letter from string for comparison without these numbers?

**Update:** Letter will be found if

```
std::vector<std::string> vLetters = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

change to

```
std::vector<char> vLetters = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
```

However, it would be nice to know how to change the code without changing vector of strings.

Comment: `&letter == vLetters[0]` makes no sense

Comment: You should focus on the symptoms you see and less on the conclusions you have come to. In particular, all data gets stored as bit patterns. The bit pattern representing the letter `A` is `0100 0001`. The bit pattern representing the number `65` is `0100 0001`. Asking how you can get the bit pattern `0100 0001` without having the bit pattern `0100 0001` is asking for the impossible. Focus on the actual output of your program, compared to the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

`&letter` is a `char*`. `char*` is a special type in the world of pointers. It is treated like a pointer to a C style NULL terminated character array. `&letter == vLetters[0]` tries to form a `std::string` from `&letter`, which is not NULL terminated. Hence the undefined behavior.